# HTML 5 with brightcove video?

Tags: javascript, css, brightcove

Current I'm using brightcove video plugin to play the video, I don't want to show the black background color in player while playing the video and same as scale the video to whole player screen, i tried to set the aspect ratio for a video as suggested by brightcove video.

I can able to implement this for a single video but in my case is multiple videos from API, and i refered below link but i'm not able to get currentHeight() value.

https://support.brightcove.com/sizing-player#Size_in_the_Player_API

```
.video-js {
      height: 300px;
      width: 220px;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the width and height on the video-js element. I would suggest to set them to 100% and position it to absolute keeping your wrapper to position relative. You will have to maintain the ratio though so that your videos do not clip unevenly.